# Cannot retrieve a list of campaigns for some accounts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I'm experiencing troubles requesting list of campaigns for some accounts. I'm requesting data with C# SDK , and my query is pretty simple: `/v2.2/act_<account id>/adcampaign_groups`.

For some accounts this works fine, but for some it returns OAuthException #10 (You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action).

The result is the same when using Graph Explorer, so it doesn't seem like SDK issue. I also get the same error when requesting `/v2.2/act_<account id>`. But I see this account with all its properties when requesting `/v2.2/me/adaccounts`.

I have administrator permissions in ads cabinet, and I can see campaigns for these faulty accounts in web UI, so I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work.

Any help?

Comment: What level of access do you have to the API? Are you *sure* the user whose token you're using has permission to access that account? (e.g. you don't just have permission to see the account exists via business manager, or the ability to access reports only?)

Comment: @Igy, my token has `public_profile, email, ads_management, ads_read` permissions, and I'm pretty sure it belongs to the user I'm using to access business manager (just confirmed it with token debugger). If I go to business manager settings and select my user from the list of people, I see it has all existings accounts in "assigned accounts", and all of them have "admin" role assigned. I've even tried to delete and re-assign role, still no luck.

Comment: If you're sure of all of that, and are aware of the which access level your app has to the API and the restrictions therein ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/access ), i recommend filing a bug report - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Okay, I think you're right, I actually met those restrictions. It was a bit confusing though, because I didn't explicitly specified all the accounts, so FB automatically filled them on first come, first serve basis. The API worked until there was room left for it to auto add accounts, and for the rest it just stopped working returning unclear error. Thanks for your help.